# XMPPFarmework How to obtain XMPP chat room list in iOS?

Tags: xmpp, xmppframework

XMPPFarmework       us openfire

How to obtain XMPP chat room list  in iOS  ?
Anyone please show me a way to solve out this.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code works for us when connected to an `ejabberd` server on `Amazon EC2` and hope it should work for `Openfire` too.

```
- (void) getChatRooms:(XMPPStream *)stream
{
    NSString* server = @"conference.myserver.com";
    XMPPJID *servrJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:server];
    XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get" to:servrJID];

    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"chatroom_list"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[stream myJID].full];
    NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query"];
    [query addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"];
    [iq addChild:query];
    [firstStream sendElement:iq];
}

- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@", [iq description]);    
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm getting multiple query responses, How can I differentiate between them?